# How can I iterate over ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, database, django, orm, model

A simple question and yet I can't find an answer for it.

I have a model with a ManyToMany field:

```
class Stuff(models.Model):
  things = models.ManyToManyField(Thing)
```

then in a different function I want to do this:

```
myStuff = Stuff.objects.get(id=1)
for t in myStuff.things.all:
  # ...
```

But that is giving me:

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable
```

How can I iterate over a manyToManyField ?

Comment: "instancemethod object" should have tipped you off that it's a method (needs parentheses), not an iterable.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Try adding the `()` after `all`: `myStuff.things.all()`

Comment: In the template use `myStuff.things.all` (omitting the ())

Answer (score 2):

Like Abid A already answered, you are missing brackets ()

```
for t in myStuff.things.all():
    print t.myStuffs.all()
```

Comment: why'd you repeat it then? and your example is broken... what are you trying to print (there's a colon at the end)?

Comment: By then I did not have a permission to write comments here and my purpose was to show a real working example of for-loop printing the things all stuffs that you was not able to show. A colon is there because in Python a for-loop always needs one!

Comment: I believe I was referring to the extra colon you edited out. But fair enough... I do find complete examples easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

ManyToManyField seems to have a different kind of Manager than your basic Django class.  Looking at the source here, https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L821, it seems you are looking for the related_val field which appears to contain the tuple of related objects references.

Comment: ah I made a mistake, Abid A's answer does work in fact. :$